# How do I return only those searched records whose isActive property is true?

Tags: ember.js

In an ember app and I'm trying to return records that match the search term and isActive equals true.  The search part works, I just can't get the isActive true to work with the rest of it.

```
filterDecks(search) {
  if (search.length < 2) {
    return;
  }
  // keep it local™
  search = search.toLowerCase();

  let decks = this.store.peekAll('deck').filter(function(item) {
    let title = (item.get('title') || '').toLowerCase();
    let description = (item.get('description') || '').toLowerCase();
    let tags = (item.get('tags') || []).toString().toLowerCase();
    let isActive  = (item.get('isActive'));

    return title.includes(search) ||
        description.includes(search) ||
        tags.includes(search);
  }, this);

  this.set('filteredDecks', decks);
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain filters, and notice embers `filterBy`:

```
let decks = this.store.peekAll('deck').filter((item) => {
    let title = (item.get('title') || '').toLowerCase();
    let description = (item.get('description') || '').toLowerCase();
    let tags = (item.get('tags') || []).toString().toLowerCase();

    return title.includes(search) ||
        description.includes(search) ||
        tags.includes(search);
}).filterBy('isActive', true);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can include `isActive` condition along with searchterm.

```
let decks = this.store.peekAll('deck').filter((item) => {
    let title = (item.get('title') || '').toLowerCase();
    let description = (item.get('description') || '').toLowerCase();
    let tags = (item.get('tags') || []).toString().toLowerCase();
    let isActive = (item.get('isActive'));

    return ((title.includes(search) ||
        description.includes(search) ||
        tags.includes(search)) && isActive);
});
```